# Is asking questions on interpretation of profiler analyses on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

I'd like to ask a question on how to interpret the (JVM) profiler results of two implementations.

The intention is to *reassure my understanding of the profiler results and my ability to interpret them correctly*.

I do not assume the profiler is wrong. I assume my understanding of its output is wrong.

After that I can either go back to the drawing board or ask a more precise questions (here or on the Code Review stack) to help improving the performance of my implementation(s) or to understand the bottlenecks of the code.

I'd provide:

- how I've profiled the code
- the profiler results
- my interpretation of the results
- the code using two implementations (classes) but not the code behind the the two classes since it does not contribute

---

1. Is such a question on-topic? What would be the proper site instead if any?
2. Is it OK to spare the code (mainly for brevity reasons and to avoid off-topic discussion on the code itself, preventing the question to get "too broad")?

Comment: Very doubtful.  Without the actual code to look at it is [gorilla vs shark](https://www.google.com/search?q=gorilla+vs+shark).  Just assume that the profiler is not lying to you and ask why the specific implementation is slower.

Comment: I can certainly imagine ways you could phrase such a question where it would be on-topic, but I would still prefer that you do as Hans suggested: "ask why the specific implementation is slower". Let the answerers explain the difference between the two code snippets to you, which would effectively be the same thing as explaining the profiler output. Including relevant code snippets does not make the question "too broad"; quite the opposite.

Comment: @CodyGray I thought of this as the second step. I'd like to reassure that I am able to read and understand the profiler results perfectly because it's a basic skill that does not only apply to the current programming problem. When the profiler outputs are quite similar (called methods, call stacks, call counts) because the underlying code is only slightly different I don't see a reason why the code would help to acknowledge my understanding of the results. Hans Passant, I'm not assuming the profiler is lying but I'm unsure on my understanding of the analysis.

Comment: Hmya, that's how this always goes off into the deep end.  In this last comment you assert that you are able to read and understand the results *and* that you are unsure.  Nobody can make hay of that.